# How many indexes can I give the GLES20.glDrawElements function?

Tags: java, opengl, android-studio

I want to draw an more complex object with opengl in android Studio.
I have a mesh. All vertices normals and indexes are correct.

But when I come to this function `GLES20.glDrawElements(mode, count, type,  indices)`  I have the problem that when count is for example 1661 or higher the app breaks. But when count is 1381 of lower it works fine (exept for the fact that my object looks wrong).

I thought that there could be two possible reasons for that. First the number is just to high and the method has a limit on how many objects it can draw .(But I haven´t found anything aubout it and I don´t think that 1700 is such a high number of indexes!)

An other possibility is that somehow I defined the frame or space wrong in which openGl draws. I am working with Vuforia and am using the Vuforia sample project. When I put in a small count number and opengl actually draws something, it is all in a small area of the image target. But since I use the sample I have no idea where you would define something like that.

If anyone has an idea I would really appriciate!

EDIT:
This is what happens in the Logcat:

D/libEGL﹕ glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 1661, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const void *) 0x899e56d0);

A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xe34s5654 in tid 65432 (GLThread 8537)

E/BufferQueueProducer﹕ [unnamed-] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=7 undequeued=1)

And than the last report is repeated a couple times...

Comment: The range of indices you can use during a `glDrawElements()` call depends on the _actual array data provided_ in all of the enabled vertex attrib arrays at the time of the draw call. To me, this seems like you just index to non-existing vertices.

Comment: @derhass Thanks for your comment! Tested it but the highest index is never higher than the length of my vertices array/3 -1. So the vertex for each index should exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no defined limit for the number of indices you can pass to `glDrawElements()`, aside from the inherent limits of the data types.

ES 2.0 supports two index types:

- `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, with a maximum value of 255.
- `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`, with a maximum value of 65,535.

To be precise: The above are limits on the *maximum index value*, not the *number of indices* you can pass to `glDrawElements()`. So if indices are used multiple times, the number of indices could actually be higher than this limit. Still, this is what typically limits how much geometry you can draw with a single call.

If you're using `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` for the indices, you should definitely be able to use a couple of thousand indices.

The only legitimate explanation I can think of is that the device runs out of memory if the vertex data gets too large. You could try calling `glGetError()`, and see if you get any `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` errors. Even though, those errors tend to not be reported reliably.

Other than that, there are two possible explanations:

1. Your code is broken.
2. The OpenGL implementation on the device is broken.

It's impossible to tell which of the two it is without seeing the critical parts of your code.

Comment: So I am using GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT and I have index values higher than 66 (also higher than 255). So that must be the problem. But what am I to do now? Because I have a very large object. How do other people do it because having 256 different verts can´t be that special.

Comment: @HHHH For `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`, the maximum would be 65535 (see second bullet point). I'm not sure what the convention is in your country, but in the US (and I believe most other English speaking countries), the comma is the "thousands separator", while we use a period as the decimal point. So 65,535 is sixty-five thousand five hundred thirty five (or 2^16 - 1).